# HTML Checkbox Return value?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Below is my code, I am trying to make it display the result of the order, however I cant get it to appear, I believe the return value of checkbox maybe some other than true, so I tried using  `var checkedt5 = $("t5").is(':checked');` but i am getting errors where the onclick on order will not work. I believe theres is an error in the function.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Form </title>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- hide from uneducated browsers
function Order()
{
  var size = document.getElementById("pizzasize").value
  var crust = document.getElementById("pizzacrust").value
  var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").value
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").value
  var t3 = document.getElementById("t3").value
  var t4 = document.getElementById("t4").value
  var t5 = document.getElementById("t5").value
  var checkedt1 = $("t1").is(':checked');
  var checkedt2 = $("t2").is(':checked');
  var checkedt3 = $("t3").is(':checked');
  var checkedt4 = $("t4").is(':checked');
  var checkedt5 = $("t5").is(':checked');



    document.write("<p>")
document.write("Your order is in process <br /> ")
       document.write("Pizza Size = " + size + "<br />")
       document.write("Pizza Crust = " + crust + "<br />")
 if (checkedt1 == true)
 {
 document.write("Toppings = " + t1 + "<br />")
 }
 if (checkedt2 == true)
 {
 document.write("Toppings = " + t2 + "<br />")
 }
     if (checkedt3 == true)
     {
 document.write("Toppings = " + t3 + "<br />")
 }
     if (checkedt4 == true)
     {
 document.write("Toppings = " + t4 + "<br />")
 }
     if (checkedt5 == true)
     {
 document.write("Toppings = " + t5 + "<br />")
 }
     document.write("Your order will be delivered as soon as possible")

   return ""
   }

    // end hiding from uneducated browsers  -->
    </script>

  <style TYPE="text/css">
  body 
  {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <h1>Mateo's Pizzeria</h1>
  <form>
     <b>Pizza Size</b>: 
     <select name="pizzasize" id="pizzasize">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a              size</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
    <option value="x-large">X-Large</option>
    <option value="omg">OMG</option>
  </select>
     <p>
     <b>Pizza Crust</b>: 
     <select name="pizzacrust" id="pizzacrust">
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a crust type</option>
    <option value="thin">Thin</option>
    <option value="thick">Thick</option>
    <option value="sicilian">Sicilian</option>
  </select>
     <p>

 <b>Pizza Toppings</b>:
     <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t1" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t2" value="sausage">Sausage<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t3" value="mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t4" value="black-olives">Block              Olives<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="t5" value="pineapple">Pineapple<br>


  </select>
     <p>
     <b>Confirmed Order</b>: <output TYPE="text" NAME="output" ID="outputID" SIZE="50"             WIDTH="50" />
     </p><p>
     <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Confirm Order" onClick="Order()" />
     </p><p>
     <!--// <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Process Input 2" onClick="newProcess()" /> -->
  </p></form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the [# for selecting by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
var checkedt1 = $("#t1").is(':checked');
var checkedt2 = $("#t2").is(':checked');
var checkedt3 = $("#t3").is(':checked');
var checkedt4 = $("#t4").is(':checked');
var checkedt5 = $("#t5").is(':checked');
```

Comment: I have added # to each of the elements as requested, however, i am still unable to run it

Comment: @user2951224 include jQuery in your page.